# How to print the value within a function of python?

Tags: python

This is my function in python, I do not know how to print the node I want...

```
class trie_node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children1 = dict()  
        self.valid = False

class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = trie_node()

    def insert(self, word: str) -> None:
        node = self.root
        for l in word:
            # print(l)
            if l not in node.children1:
                node.children1[l] = trie_node()
                node = node.children1[l]  # This is what I want to print out!! the value of children1.....
                # print(node.children1[l])
                node.valid = True
obj = Trie()
print(obj.insert('apple'))
```

I have tried to add print(node) here...But it does not work and shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(obj.insert('apple'))
  File "2.py", line 18, in insert
    print(node.children1[l])
KeyError: 'a'
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You just changed `node` to be one of its children. You have no guarantee the child has its own child with the same key. But if you just want to print out the original child, you have it; you assigned it to `node`. So just change the code to:

```
def insert(self, word: str) -> None:
    node = self.root
    for l in word:
        # print(l)
        if l not in node.children1:
            node.children1[l] = trie_node()
            node = node.children1[l]  # This is what I want to print out!! the value of children1.....
            print(node)  # node is now the same thing the original node's .children1[l] value
            node.valid = True
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you!! It really print something like: <__main__.trie_node object at 0x0000023E150E46D0>   (but is not a real word value....)
But if I want to print out the inner structure which shows higher or lower level between the word? Such as, this is a trie data structure, if I insert both "apple" and then "append", I can see the "app" shared, and then "le" ~ "end" at the same level...

Comment: @Frank: Easiest way is to define a useful `__repr__` (or `__str__`, though `__repr__` alone will be used when `__str__` is invoked if you only define `__repr__`) to do that, and `print` will use it automatically. Your code would likely need to traverse up and down the trie to do it, and that's a big, and separate, question from the one you asked. I'd suggest doing some research and trying it yourself; if you can't make it work, post a new question with a [MCVE] of what's not working.